# How to off the IDENTITY column of table in TSQL

Tags: identity-insert

i used 'SET IDENTITY_INSERT  OFF' and this is executing successfully but in the table still identity on only

please help any one

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is going to drive you crazy but to do what you want use

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON
```

This [article](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/how-to-insert-values-into-an-identity-column-in-sql-server) explains it.

The gist is that however misguided the decision, someone made the call that this statement would refer to whether your scripts could alter the identity column.  Rather backwards, but that's just the way it is :D

Comment: Yes, setting it to ON means it allows you to insert identity column value manually. OFF = auto insert by the system.